# how to convert escaped hexadecimal to ascii in python

Tags: python-3.x, escaping, hex

I have a value which looks like this

```
b'\xe7t\xb6\x06[\xbf\xf5]y\xd7\xa1\xd785\xbe\xe7\t'
```

how to print it as a ASCII clean string in Python 3.5
I've been searching the internet i didn't find any clue...

Comment: Why do you think this is supposed to be readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems like a bytes. You can decode it by using a proper codec.

For example:

```
>>> b'\xe7t\xb6\x06[\xbf\xf5]y\xd7\xa1\xd785\xbe\xe7\t'.decode('latin-1')

'çt¶\x06[¿õ]y×¡×85¾ç\t'
```

But it's a pretty meaningless..

What encoding are you use? What is the origin of these bytes?
I tried to use standard codecs and got this result:

```
cp037: XÈ¶$×5)`P~P´X
cp424: X ¶$×5)`P~P´X
cp437: τt╢[┐⌡]y╫í╫85╛τ
cp500: XÈ¶$×5)`P~P´X
cp720: قt╢[┐ُ]y╫ة╫85╛ق
cp737: ύt╢[┐Ϋ]y╫κ╫85╛ύ
cp775: ńtČ[┐§]yūĪū85Šń
cp850: þtÂ[┐§]yÎíÎ85¥þ
cp852: štÂ[┐§]yÎíÎ85żš
cp855: уtХ[┐ш]yОАО85Йу
cp858: þtÂ[┐§]yÎíÎ85¥þ
cp860: τt╢[┐⌡]y╫í╫85╛τ
cp861: τt╢[┐⌡]y╫í╫85╛τ
cp862: τt╢[┐⌡]y╫í╫85╛τ
cp863: τt╢[┐⌡]y╫´╫85╛τ
cp864: ﻫt٦[؟ﻰ]yﻁ­ﻁ85ﺹﻫ
cp865: τt╢[┐⌡]y╫í╫85╛τ
cp866: чt╢[┐ї]y╫б╫85╛ч
cp869: νtΛ[┐§]yβΐβ85Ον
cp874: ็tถ[ฟ๕]yืกื85พ็
cp875: X ό$ψ5)`P~PχX
cp1006: ﻝtﭘ[ﺟﺀ]yﻉ۰ﻉ85ﺝﻝ
cp1026: XÈ¶İ×5)ıPöP´X
cp1140: XÈ¶$×5)`P~P´X
cp1250: çt¶[żő]y×ˇ×85ľç
cp1251: зt¶[їх]yЧЎЧ85ѕз
cp1252: çt¶[¿õ]y×¡×85¾ç
cp1253: ηt¶[Ώυ]yΧ΅Χ85Ύη
cp1254: çt¶[¿õ]y×¡×85¾ç
cp1255: חt¶[¿ץ]y׳¡׳85¾ח
cp1256: çt¶[؟ُ]y×،×85¾ç
cp1258: çt¶[¿ơ]y×¡×85¾ç
latin_1: çt¶[¿õ]y×¡×85¾ç
iso8859_2: çtś[żő]y×Ą×85žç
iso8859_4: įtļ[ŋõ]y×Ą×85žį
iso8859_5: чtЖ[Пѕ]yзЁз85Оч
iso8859_7: ηtΆ[Ώυ]yΧ‘Χ85Ύη
iso8859_9: çt¶[¿õ]y×¡×85¾ç
iso8859_10: įtķ[ŋõ]yŨĄŨ85ūį
iso8859_13: ēt¶[æõ]y×”×85¾ē
iso8859_14: çt¶[ṡõ]yṪḂṪ85ẅç
iso8859_15: çt¶[¿õ]y×¡×85Ÿç
iso8859_16: çt¶[żő]yŚĄŚ85Ÿç
koi8_r: Гt╤[©У]yв║в85╬Г
koi8_u: ГtІ[©У]yв║в85╬Г
mac_cyrillic: зtґ[њх]y„°„85Њз
mac_greek: γtΕ[Ωθ]yΉΓΉ85Ψγ
mac_iceland: Át∂[øı]y◊°◊85æÁ
mac_latin2: Át∂[Ņű]y◊°◊85ĺÁ
mac_roman: Át∂[øı]y◊°◊85æÁ
mac_turkish: Át∂[ø]y◊°◊85æÁ
ptcp154: зt¶[ҝх]yЧЎЧ85ҫз
```

Comment: It's encrypted text.. it should be readable after decrypting but I couldn't pass this escaped chars..